# I am trying to use Salesforce Analytics API to Download a Lightning Experience Dashboard as a PNG but I am getting resource not found error

Tags: apex, rest-api, dashboard, analytics-api

I am referring to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_download_example_le_dashboard_png.htm
url from Salesforce in order to download image of my dashboard (Lightning Experience Dashboard). I am making the callout within my Salesforce Org using Apex but for some reason I am getting below response:

```
 "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
 "message" : "The requested resource does not exist"
```

I tried using workbench but still the same error is coming. From the doc I have given the prerequisite permissions from my side related to Slack and now I am stuck as the API is not working for me.

Although as I said that workbench is also giving the same error still i am posting my Apex code for reference:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setEndpoint('https://xxxx-xxxxx.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/analytics/download/dashboard/01Z2w000000VXOzEAO.png');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+Userinfo.getSessionId());
            
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

req.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
system.debug('response-->' + res.getbody());
```

What am i doing wrong here as I belive I have followed the documentation correctly.

Comment: You could try changing the application type, because you don't want JSON - you want `image/png`